# Comparing two uk postcode values for match and part match ignoring spaces and case

Tags: ms-access, vba, fuzzy-logic

I would like to compare two uk postcode strings in a ms access database vba function.

I want to first identify if the postcodes match.  Ignoring and case sensitivity or spaces between the incode and outcodes if they are present in either postcode strings.

If they don't match entirely then I would like to return the number of characters that do match

E.g. A841JD and A84 1XJ would return 4 and AB41 1JD and Ab411jD would return true.

How would I go about coding this.  I get stuck when taking out any space characters to compare on with for next loops on comparing byte arrays.

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet here, so that SO can try to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if replace(lcase(range("A1").value)," ","") = replace(lcase(range("A2").value)," ","") then
    'Do something
end if
```

Comment: Great! Could you please mark your question as answered, to keep this website clean? :)

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the question as answered!